# Command to use restoring npm packages

Tags: npm, npm-install

When I download a project from my repo with a `package.json` in its root, which command is the right one to use `npm install` or `npm install restore`?

Answer (score 90, accepted):

The behaviour of `npm install` is

- `npm install` without any argument will install all packages found in `package.json` in `node_modules` folder.
- `npm install <package_name>` will install `package_name`. In your case will download `restore` package and will save it in `node_modules` folder. (https://www.npmjs.com/package/restore)

Comment: Looks like restore has nothing to do with restoring packages. That package seems to be about remote storage. Thank you!

Answer (score 10):

Just type:

```
npm i
```

From help:

```
>npm i -h

npm install (with no args, in package dir)
npm install [<@scope>/]<pkg>
npm install [<@scope>/]<pkg>@<tag>
npm install [<@scope>/]<pkg>@<version>
npm install [<@scope>/]<pkg>@<version range>
npm install <folder>
npm install <tarball file>
npm install <tarball url>
npm install <git:// url>
npm install <github username>/<github project>

aliases: i, isntall, add
common options: [--save-prod|--save-dev|--save-optional] [--save-exact] [--no-save]
```